# Proxy + requests. Зависает подключение

Tags: python, proxy, requests

Требуется подключиться к сайту через рандомно выбранный из списка прокси сервер. Список загружается из файла.
В принципе всё работает, но есть одно но. А именно: соединение через прокси зависает и программа не может завершится.
Таймауты и `try/except` выставлены верно, но это не спасает. Как быть?

```
import requests
import random
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

with open('\\proxy.txt' , 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as proxy_file:
    proxy_lines = proxy_file.readlines()

ii = 1
while ii < 1000:
    proxy_line = proxy_lines[random.randint(1, len(proxy_lines)-1)].strip()
    session = requests.session()
    session.temeout = (3)
    Adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(pool_connections = 1, pool_maxsize = 0, max_retries = 0)
    session.mount('http://', Adapter)
    session.mount('https://', Adapter)
    session.proxies = {
        'http' : proxy_line,
        'https' : proxy_line
    }
    try:
        request = session.post('https://www.site.com/')
        print('Подключение удалось | ' + proxy_line)
        request.close
    except Exception as exception:
        #print(exception)
        print('Подключение не удалось. Переподключение. ' + proxy_line)
    ii = ii + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно Вы ошиблись, у Session нет атрибута `session.temeout` и `session.timeout` тоже.
Вам необходимо задавать `timeout` параметром при вызове `post`:
`request = session.post('https://www.site.com/', timeout=3)`

Документация по объекту Session: [requests.Session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#sessionapi)